# How to display the value of a variable with its name in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I have some variables like

```
x = symbols('x0:2')
y = x[0] + x[1]
```

If I display `y` it shows:

[image]

How can I get output like: y=x<sub>0</sub>+x<sub>1</sub>

Comment: Can't you just `print('y=' + str(y))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entering `Eq(S('y'), y)` will have the desired effect; it creates a formal equality statement between a symbol "y" and the value assign to `y`.  It has an advantage over `'y=' + str(y)` in that the value is not stringified, allowing for LaTeX processing when enabled. A screenshot from http://live.sympy.org:

[image: live.sympy.org]

Comment: You may need `Eq(S('y'), y, evaluate=False)` to prevent sympy reducing trivially true statements to `True` or `False`.